# How do I read Adobe LiveCycle Rights Management protected PDF using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, pdfbox, rights-management

My objective is to create a custom PDF manager and viewer desktop application, and I've decided to use JavaFX with the PDFBox library.

The problem I'm encountering right now is that the PDF files that are supposed to be opened by the application are protected by/with Adobe LifeCycle Rights Management where it requires a username and password to open.

I've done some research but there doesn't seem to be a detailed solution for the same problem. Any help or a general direction from this roadblock is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need two things. 1) The Adobe LiveCycle Portable Protection Library which is a C++ SDK that allows programmatic access to the Rights Management component of your Adobe LiveCycle instance. Because PDFBox is Java, you'll need some way of wrapping that library. 2) An account on the Adobe LiveCycle Rights Management server that secured the file.

If you just have the files but can't access the server, you won't be able to decrypt the file.